# rails no such file to load -- ap (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try any of the `rails`, `rake` command in staging server I got `no such file to load -- ap (LoadError)`,

for `rails s`:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`require': no such file to load -- ap (LoadError)    
 xxxx    
/config/application.rb:7
```

for `rake -T`:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ap
```

my `application.rb` file:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production. 

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

my rails and ruby  version:

- rails version in local and staging: 3.0.11
- ruby version in staging: ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358)
- ruby version in local:ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352)

But I can run `rails s`, `rails c`, `rake log:clear` everything in my local machine. `Gemfile` file in staging is same as `Gemfile` in local.

what am I missing here? how can I resolve this?

Comment: there is line in gemfile `group :development, :test do  gem "awesome_print", :require => "ap" end`. but `gem list ap` didn't print anything in console

Comment: did you try using `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: `bundle exec  rails s --without development test`

Comment: same error for `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: I think that you should update your application to rails 3 with ruby 1.9.x because ruby 1.8.7 is totally deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

In your `Gemfile`, change this line:

```
gem "awesome_print", :require => "ap"
```

...to this:

```
gem "awesome_print"
```

I just had the same thing happen to me.  `ap` is a custom defined alias for `awesome_print`.  This allows you to do things like `ap Product.first` and it will pretty print it for you.  Much easier than typing out `awesome_print Product.first`

I'm not sure why, but when this happened to me, I dropped the alias, and it loaded without an issue. There is probably something else in play here that someone smarter than myself can explain, but I know that this worked for me.